# Scrollable sidebar using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a website H1Z1Atlas.com and I have a problem where when the sidebar content extends past the page, the sidebar does not have a scrollable causing the content to be not shown.

I'm using a twitter bootstrap navbar as well on the page is there any easy fix to get a dynamic scrollbar?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Wb5.jpg

Here is a link to the picture. there are more rows of layers however when the screen size becomes to small they just disappear instead of showing a sidebar. The html is a bit confusing due to angular.js so it would be hard to show properly

Edit: I would like the sidebar to be the same as this page https://material.angularjs.org/#/ where you can scroll the content

Comment: Might be best to show some code in your question.

Comment: I tried finding what you were talking about, but I was unable. Can you at least provide a picture?

Comment: Add overflow: auto; to your #sidebar-wrapper

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work because we don't have a height specified. is it possible to do this with height:100% set

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to suggest anything without some code. But you said you are using twitter bootstrap so I suggest doing the following and I hope it will solve your problem.

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Good luck.

If only need the vertical scroll, that would be:

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the overflow-y style to work you have to set height in px or %. Otherwise div remains hidden outside of the view.

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 500px;
 width: 295px;
}
```