# Bootstrap Sidebar Not Scrollable 100% Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a Bootstrap Sidebar on the left part of my screen. `height` is set to `100%`. But when content goes past the bottom of the screen it's not scrollable.

I saw [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375553/scrollable-sidebar-using-bootstrap#28376048) question which is very similar to my problem. One of the comments mentions that it could be due to my height being set to 100%.

I have tried to set my height to 100px just as a test to see if the content would become scrollable, and that worked.

So my question is, is there a way to make the content in my sidebar scrollable and keep the height at `100%` instead of having to set a specific pixel value?

**Edit:**

Below is my current CSS for `#sidebar-wrapper`.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 175px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -175px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #222222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

After going through the code specific to the website. The fixed positioned sidebar needed the CSS property `top:52px` which offsets the sidebar in the top to accomodate the navbar of height `52px` and `bottom:0px` which is added to ensure the sidebar extends to the bottom of the browser window.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 175px;
    top: 52px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: -175px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #222222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

**Old Answer:**

Here is some sample code from [bootsnipp.com/](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sidebar-navigation-with-scrollspy) and a simple working snippet of the code. Refer the below JSFiddle.

So if the code is structured in this format, then bootstrap will take care of the sidebar scrolling internally, if you need to add scroll always then add the CSS property `overflow-y:scroll` to the ID `#sidebar-wrapper`

The below CSS is what I am talking about.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: I just updated the question with my CSS. That link you provided isn't quite my problem. On the sidebar there are like 4 anchors. Imagine the content in the sidebar is a lot more. So the content doesn't fit into the height of the sidebar. I want that sidebar to be scrollable so users can scroll to see all the content.

Comment: @CharlieFish the jsfiddle link I gave has a lot of content so a scrollbars is added when the content is greater than the sidebar....could you please tell me the exact problem with the code in the jsfiddle!

Comment: Looks like that link you provided works when I edit it. Let me play around with my code a bit more to try to narrow the question further.

Comment: @CharlieFish ok, keep me posted!

Comment: @CharlieFish There share a JSfiddle with the issue replicated and I will check it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156223/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-naren-murali).